# rake db schema dump is not creating tables dumps for non dbo schema tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In my rails application i am using MS SQL database. I have two schema in my application. A few tables are in dbo schema and a few are in Employee schema. When I run rake db:schema:dump, it is creating schema.rb file. But this file contains tables for dbo schema only. It's not creating tables for Employee schema.

Comment: I am experiencing exactly the same behavior.  Schema dump is only picking up tables for dbo schema items.  Using MS SQL Server and tiny tds as the connector